# Como trabalhar com UILongPressGestureRecognizer em Swift usando tabelas?

Tags: ios, swift

Preciso que quando o usuário pressionar a célula da tabela apareça um alerta com informações.

Segue código

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = "Bem da Água"
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let linha = indexPath.row
        println("Selecionou \(linha)")

        let Gest = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "showAlerta:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(Gest)
    }

    func showAlerta(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            var alerta = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let show = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler:nil)

            alerta.addAction(show)

            presentViewController(alerta,animated:true,completion:nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso adicionar o gesto na própria célula, dentro do `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, por exemplo:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier") as! UITableViewCell

    let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "showAlerta:")
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    return cell
}
```

E para obter o *index path* da célula pressionada, no seu método `showAlerta` faça:

```
func showAlerta(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    var point: CGPoint = sender.locationInView(tableView)
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Aqui me retorna um erro cara no  identifier cell

Comment: Não sei como está esse seu método, que é como você monta a sua célula, então fiz uma suposição para definir a variável `cell`.

Comment: Exatamente como você colocou

Comment: Pode especificar melhor o erro? Não consegui identificar onde exatamente está o erro que você citou.

Comment: Ignore esse erro, pois foi um descuido que tive e foi resolvido.